# DF Test Rejects Non-Stationarity in a seemingly Non-Stationary Series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

Let $Y_t = \rho Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ and $Y_0$ be some constant.

I generated a time series data for the above model like this

```
y=rnorm(1,5,1)
for(i in 1:100)
  y=append(y,tail(y,1)+rnorm(1,1,1))
```

[image: Plot of the time series data y_t]

The above is a plot of the same. Now to test the stationarity of this series I used the `adf.test` function from the package `tseries` in `R`. For the above model a Dickey-Fuller Test (i.e adf test with 0 lag) should be enough (and appropriate too) to test for stationarity. However the output of the following code:

```
> adf.test(y,k = 0)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  y
Dickey-Fuller = -3.4732, Lag order = 0, p-value = 0.04793
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Tells that the null hypothesis is rejected at the 5% level and the series is stationary. While from the plot the series is clearly NOT stationary. Can someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If run your code many times and check how often you get a pvalue less than 5%:

```
S <- 10000
rejections <- rep(NA, S)
for (s in 1:S){
  y=rnorm(1,5,1)
  for(i in 1:100){
      y=append(y,tail(y,1)+rnorm(1,1,1))
  }
  reject <- (adf.test(y,k = 0)$p.value <= 0.05)
  rejections[s] <- reject
}
mean(rejections, na.rm=TRUE)
```

You see that the adf test does its job, it only incorrectly rejects the null of not stationary about 5% of the time.

The data you posted is obviously non-stationary because it seems to have a linear trend -  but the ADF implemented in adf.test uses a model that allows for a constant and a linear trend term. So if these are taken out, it can happen that the data then looks stationary.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that tseries::adf.test implementation forces a constant and a linear term. I used the urca::df after reading your answer and now things are working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The `adf.test()` from the *TsSeries* package runs the test under the assumption that there is a constant AND a trend. After considering those in your data the time series would most likely be stationary. The `adf.test()` from the aTSA function uses all three DF type tests including the one for no drift no constant, which would most likely result in non-stationary in your case. But I do not know why the `adf.test()` function is limited to only one case (trend and drift).